# Should I store executed DB queries for debugging purposes?

Tags: mysql, database, debugging

I want to be able to track the data changes in the DB of my app so I'm thinking about storing, in a dedicated DB table, all INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries that my app executes.

Would that be a bad idea?

Comment: OK, that rules out my next suggestion! ;)  What do you need to track these changes for? auditing?

Comment: It is not a requirement. I just thought it could be useful in terms of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do that in debug mode - we output all the queries to a file. Of course, this does not make sense (and is a huge performance hit) on a production server, but we can turn it on there too, for short period of debugging.
Any way - mysql has query log you can turn on, it will record every single thing it does.